# Is it ok to create a new database table for each metric?

Tags: database, database-design, datatables, bcnf

My engineering team builds a machine and records various metrics related to the machine such as battery voltage, name of the machine, number of times used etc. My current database structure has the following columns in one table

```
ID
Name of the machine
# time used
battery voltage
.
.
```

The team keeps changing the names of the machine or the metrics and they suggest that every time there is a name change a new table should automatically be created to avoid any code breaks. Eg. If the initial name was A1/BatteryVoltage the table would be

```
Id
A1/BatteryVoltage
```

Later if they change it to A1/Battery_Voltage, they want a new table to be created with following columns

```
ID
A1/Battery_Voltage
```

I have a sense that this doesn't make sense as it can bombard the database with huge number of tables. But my manager is asking me to be more concrete on why I think this doesn't make sense. I know that cost of creating tables is not much but I also know that I cannot create filters such as machine name in pulling metrics when I use this structure. I also know that I will have to create multiple joins to get one single metric. But is there anything else that can help me in convincing my team or convince myself about what my team wants?

Comment: Are the values of the metrics always the same type? If so, what type (decimal, integer, etc)?

Comment: They can be various types such as integers, floating points, strings etc. Each type in itself would remain the same. For Eg. if Battery voltage is floating point, it will continue to be floating point even if the name changes

Comment: Would it be OK if they were all stored as strings? (it would make for an easy and good solution if the answer is yes)

Comment: It can be done but how would that impact the number of tables to be created? Is my assumption incorrect to say that creating table each time a new change to the name of metric is done is not the right style of database design?

Comment: you are right to think it's a bad idea - non scaleable, poor practice, high workload for the slightest change, etc. I'll post an answer soon. What is `ID` - a surrogate row id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **one** table for everything, adding columns to discriminate metrics. Something like:

```
create table metric (
  id int, -- eg auto increment
  created timestamp,
  machine_name text, -- eg 'A1'
  attribute text, -- eg 'Battery_Voltage'
  value text -- eg '9'
)
```

Now you never have to do anything to cater for new attributes, or attribute name changes.